# Is there any guideline on how a layman giving support for another layman on their psychological problems?

Tags: therapy

I am being contacted by a stranger for having some understandings about a psychological disorder (in this case, BPD). I will help them what I know, in my ability, but I want to avoid the assumption that I know the best, or any unintended harm on their therapy. I think the form of this support has been around for a long time, and basically we can rely on common sense to operate. However, is there a complete guideline for kind of situation?

Comment: What are you asking for? If the stranger is looking for information regarding the psychological disorder I think the best course of action is to direct them to someone who has been trained and this question is off-topic for here as we cannot help regarding an individual. If the person is looking for **support** rather than formal counselling, support can be provided by a layman through providing a listening ear, but **no advice should be given unless you are trained**. Asking how to provide support can be answered here but you need to make it clear that is what you require in your question.

Comment: well, that person is in therapy already, and they only need me to provide more information about BPD (to reduce the financial burden, perhaps). If it's just an exchange for knowledge/need a listening ear, I think there is no problem. However, she has expressed some aspects of herself that I'm afraid I am not trained to be able handle the situation well. I want to know how to support her properly within my ability and limit, in case the conversation leads to something unexpected

Comment: She may wish to lighten her financial burden but providing information about BPD to a sufferer may give information not relevant to them. If you give information not relevant to her BPD presentation it could affect her outlook on the situation which can be damaging to her mental wellbeing. I would suggest leaving that aspect alone and direct her to speak to her therapist. They are there to help understand how her condition is affecting her just as much as they are there to help resolve her problems.

Comment: As for providing a listening ear, that is fine as long as no advice is given on how to resolve her problems, as I mentioned in an earlier comment.  Giving advice can unwittingly counteract her therapist's advice